# Calculate difference between 2 times in hours in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, time, date-arithmetic

I have two times - 
For eg- the current time  - 08:24 and date is 02/01/2013 in dd/mm/yyyy format
and I have another time at 13:46 and date is 31/12/2012 . So, how can I calculate the difference between the 2 times in hours using PHP. (i.e. 42.63 hours)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The term you're looking for is "date arithmetic".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Convert them both to timestamp values, and then subtract to get the difference in seconds.

```
$ts1 = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', '02/01/2013 08:24'));
$ts2 = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', '31/12/2012 13:46'));
$diff = abs($ts1 - $ts2) / 3600;
```

Comment: Edited: strtotime parses as m/d/y or d-m-y, so converted / to - before parsing

Comment: it gives the difference but its doesn't give me whether the difference is positive or negative

Comment: You can just remove the abs() call if you need preserve the sign of the difference. `($ts1 - $ts2) / 3600`

Comment: yeah it was my mistake i didnt noticed that

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to use PHP's date-related classes.  The example below uses [`DateTime::diff()`](http://php.net/datetime.diff) to get a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/class.dateinterval) object (`$interval`). It then uses the interval's properties to arrive at the total number of hours in the interval.

```
$a = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i d/m/Y', '08:24 02/01/2013');
$b = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i d/m/Y', '13:46 31/12/2012');

$interval = $a->diff($b);
$hours    = ($interval->days * 24) + $interval->h
          + ($interval->i / 60) + ($interval->s / 3600);

var_dump($hours); // float(42.633333333333)
```

Answer (score 3):

I got a simple solution, Try this one -

```
echo getTimeDiff("10:30","11:10");

function getTimeDiff($dtime,$atime)
    {
        $nextDay = $dtime>$atime?1:0;
        $dep = explode(':',$dtime);
        $arr = explode(':',$atime);
        $diff = abs(mktime($dep[0],$dep[1],0,date('n'),date('j'),date('y'))-mktime($arr[0],$arr[1],0,date('n'),date('j')+$nextDay,date('y')));
        $hours = floor($diff/(60*60));
        $mins = floor(($diff-($hours*60*60))/(60));
        $secs = floor(($diff-(($hours*60*60)+($mins*60))));
        if(strlen($hours)<2){$hours="0".$hours;}
        if(strlen($mins)<2){$mins="0".$mins;}
        if(strlen($secs)<2){$secs="0".$secs;}
        return $hours.':'.$mins.':'.$secs;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the dates as timestamps (use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) if  needed), then just subtract them, optionally take the absolute value, then divide to 3600 (number of seconds in an hour). Easy ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code is useful to get an idea about how to calculate time difference using PHP

```
function date_diff($date_1 , $date_2 , $format) {
    $datetime1 = date_create($date_1);
    $datetime2 = date_create($date_2);

    $diff = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

    return $diff->format($format);
}
```

The above function is useful to calculate difference between two times as well as dates. The dates are given as arguments with the output format.

The output format are given below:

// '%y Year %m Month %d Day %h Hours %i Minute %s Seconds'        =>  1 Year 3 Month 14 Day 11 Hours 49 Minute 36 Seconds
// '%y Year %m Month %d Day'                                    =>  1 Year 3 Month 14 Days
// '%m Month %d Day'                                            =>  3 Month 14 Day
// '%d Day %h Hours'                                            =>  14 Day 11 Hours
// '%d Day'                                                        =>  14 Days
// '%h Hours %i Minute %s Seconds'                                =>  11 Hours 49 Minute 36 Seconds
// '%i Minute %s Seconds'                                        =>  49 Minute 36 Seconds
// '%h Hours                                                    =>  11 Hours
// '%a Days

Answer (score 0):

Just putting this here, for anyone who needs to find the difference between two dates/timestamps in `Hours`, `Minutes` '**AND**' `Seconds`!!

```
$futureDate_raw = '12/13/2018'; // This is your finish date.
$fdate = strtotime($futureDate_raw);

$hours   = (($fdate - time()) / 3600;
$mins    = (($fdate - time()) % 3600) / 60;
$seconds = ((($fdate- time()) % 3600) % 60);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this is simplest way to find time difference, it always works for me

```
$timestamp1 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i'));
$timestamp2 = strtotime("2020-04-05 18:00");

  $diff = abs($timestamp2 - $timestamp1)/(60*60);
echo $diff;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code is useful to get time difference with format H:I:S:

**Method 1 :**

```
function time_diff($startDateTime, $endDateTime) {
    $startDateTime = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $startDateTime));
    $endDateTime = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $endDateTime));
    $difference = abs($startDateTime - $endDateTime);
    $hours = floor($difference / 3600);
    $minutes = floor(($difference % 3600) / 60);
    $seconds = $difference % 60;

    return str_pad($hours, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT). ":" . str_pad($minutes, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT). ":" . str_pad($seconds, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

**Method 2 :**

```
function time_diff($startDateTime, $endDateTime) {
    $datetime1 = new DateTime($startDateTime);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($endDateTime);
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

    return $interval->format('%H:%I:%S');
}
```

Thank You!