# Function that calculates the time difference but takes into account only the hours in PHP

Tags: php

I have a calendar in which the user can save events. Each event has a `$start_time` and an `$end_time`. The times are saved in `HH:mm:ss` format. Is there a function which calculates the differnce between the two times but takes into account only the hours, not minutes and seconds? For instance if `$start_time = 09.00.00` and `$end_time = 12.00.00` then `difference(start_time, end_time)` should be `3`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate difference between 2 times in hours in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879373/calculate-difference-between-2-times-in-hours-in-php)

Comment: I've flagged this as a duplicate as the answer is already on SO. The only additional thing you need to do to get just the hours (as I assume you want it as a whole number) is round the number of hours the above answer produces down to a whole number.

Comment: Do you need to take the shift for daylight savings into account?

Comment: Are the two times always guaranteed to be on the same day? Is it impossible to have multi-day events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the difference by parsing the string into a numeric format with the `strtotime()` function, then calculate the time delta and parse it back to a string representation with `date()`, like so:

```
$delta = strtotime($end_time) - strtotime($start_time);
$timediff = date('H', $delta);
```

Or you can strip out the seconds and minutes before the substraction like so:

```
$end_time_hrs = date('H', strtotime($end_time));
$start_time_hrs = date('H', strtotime($start_time));
```

And then the difference:

```
$delta = strtotime($end_time_hrs) - strtotime($start_time_hrs);
$timediff = date('H', $delta);
```

Comment: Added minor correction to `date()` functions. Hope this meets with your approval.

Comment: Of course it does, thanks! Sorry for the shameful mistake too…

Answer (score 1):

The `DateTime` class has a method to compare dates -

```
$start = new DateTime('04:13:41');  // accepts the same formats as strtotime
$end = new DateTime('08:31:13');
$diff = $start->diff($end);         // pass 'true' as the second param for absolute
echo $diff->h;                      // 'h' contains the difference in hours
```