# time difference between two datetime only in hours

Tags: php

how to get time difference between two datetime only in hours

my code are

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2017-02-06 04:00:00 AM');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2017-02-07 04:10:00 AM');
$interval = $datetime2->diff($datetime1);
echo $interval->format('%d')." Days ".$interval->format('%h')." Hours ".$interval->format('%i')." Minutes";
```

my output is 
1 Days 0 Hours 10 Minutes

But I want output like this '24 hours 10 Minutes'

Comment: Multiple days by 24 and add it to the hours.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate difference between 2 times in hours in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879373/calculate-difference-between-2-times-in-hours-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't print the days separately, multiply it by 24 and add it to the hours.

```
echo 24*$interval->format('%d') + $interval->format('%h') . " Hours " . $interval->format('%i') . " Minutes";
```

Comment: Thanks !! I got my answer !!

Answer (score 0):

```
$interval = ($datetime2 - $datetime1 )/60/60;
```

echo $interval;

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more,

```
echo round((strtotime($datetime1) - strtotime($datetime2))/3600, 1);
```

Try this too.